# Cannot show first Data from Date

Tags: java, android, sqlite, date

i have some question about showing data from database sqlite.
if i want to show data from date like startdate and enddate. example from between 01/01/2014 and 03/01/2014. why the data only show from 02/01/2014 - 03/01/2014? where data from 01/01/2014?

and if want to show data from between 01/01/2014 and 01/01/2014, the data cannot show?

Here the program that i have :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/cover" >

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" >

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/no_id"
        android:layout_width="30dip"
        android:text="@string/id_label"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="70dip"
    android:text="@string/date_label"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/time"
            android:layout_width="90dip"
            android:text="@string/time_label"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/status"
    android:layout_width="100dip"
    android:text="@string/status_label"
        android:textStyle="bold" /> 
</TableRow>    

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="170dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabel_log"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

        <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" >
            <View
                    android:id="@+id/no_id1"
                    android:layout_width="30dip" />
                <View
                    android:id="@+id/date1"
                    android:layout_width="70dip" />
                <View
                    android:id="@+id/time1"
                    android:layout_width="90dip" />        
                <View
                    android:id="@+id/status1"
                    android:layout_width="100dip" />  
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

   </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/log"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textSize="12pt"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnSetDate1"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="140dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:text="@string/firstdate"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnSetDate2"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="140dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnSetDate1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnSetDate1"
    android:text="@string/enddate"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnShow"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnSetDate2"
    android:text="@string/show"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtStartDate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/btnSetDate1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnSetDate1"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/btnShow"
    android:layout_marginRight="21dp"
    android:text="@string/blank"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtEndDate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/btnSetDate2"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnSetDate2"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtStartDate"
    android:text="@string/blank"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnClear"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/btnShow"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnShow"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/btnSetDate2"
    android:text="@string/clear"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and this the database adapter :

```
public ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> ambilBarisDate(String startDate, String endDate){
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> dataArray = new 
            ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>();
    Cursor cur;
    try{
        cur = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM LOGSTAT WHERE DATE BETWEEN '"+startDate+"' AND '"+endDate+"'", null);//DIPERBAIKI

        cur.moveToFirst();

    if(!cur.isAfterLast()){
        do{
            ArrayList<Object> dataList = new ArrayList<Object>();
            dataList.add(cur.getLong(0));
            dataList.add(cur.getString(1));
            dataList.add(cur.getString(2));
            dataList.add(cur.getString(3));
            dataArray.add(dataList);
        }while (cur.moveToNext());
    }
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("DB ERROR", e.toString());
        Toast.makeText(context, "Gagal Ambil Date Baris: "+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    return dataArray;
}
```

and this java program :

```
protected void updateTable(){
while (table4data.getChildCount() > 1){
    table4data.removeViewAt(1);
}

String startDate = DateText1.getText().toString();
String endDate = DateText2.getText().toString();

ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> data = logstatsdatabase.ambilBarisDate(startDate, endDate);
for (int posisi = 0; posisi < data.size(); posisi++){
    TableRow tabelBaris = new TableRow(this);
    ArrayList<Object> baris = data.get(posisi);

    TextView idTxt = new TextView(this);
    idTxt.setText(baris.get(0).toString());
    tabelBaris.addView(idTxt);

    TextView dateTxt = new TextView(this);
    dateTxt.setText(baris.get(1).toString());
    tabelBaris.addView(dateTxt);

    TextView timeTxt = new TextView(this);
    timeTxt.setText(baris.get(2).toString());
    tabelBaris.addView(timeTxt);

    TextView statusTxt = new TextView(this);
    statusTxt.setText(baris.get(3).toString());
    tabelBaris.addView(statusTxt);

    table4data.addView(tabelBaris);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it because of this ? protected void updateTable(){
while (table4data.getChildCount() > 1){
    table4data.removeViewAt(1);
}

Comment: so whats should i do @JavaLearner? remove protected or change to public?

Answer (score 0):

Let you have a set of number 1-100. And then you say between(30-60), it will return you 31,32....58,59. If you want to include 30 and 60 in your range, you should call between(29,61). I think this answers the 1st part of your query.

The second part, between(1,1) will always be null. So in your case, if yo wish to fetch some events for a particular day between 01/01/2014 and 01/01/2014:

1. You can ommit the use of between operator and use equals operator in this case
2. Or else store your date in a LONG foramt using Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMilis(). Then you can use between operation more precisely to include the time range as well.

Comment: Yes,, all your suggest have done but still cannot show the date what i want to show.. confused?

Comment: Try hitting the function with static parameters for testing & post the updated code.